# Assign variable to another variable using SetEnvIf

Tags: apache-2.2

Apache 2.2 lacks the `<if>` directive, so I'm trying to hack around the lack of explicit if/then logic by assigning a default value to a variable but replace it if the request header includes an Origin parameter:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  SetEnvIfNoCase ORIGIN ".+" ORIGINVAR=ORIGIN
  SetEnvIfNoCase ORIGIN "^$" ORIGINVAR="*"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: %{ORIGINVAR}e
</IfModule>
```

However, I'm unable to assign ORIGINVAR ORIGIN value, I've tried:

- `ORIGIN`
- `HTTP_ORIGIN`
- `%{ORIGIN}e`
- `%{ORIGIN}`
- `"%{ORIGIN}e"`
- `"%{ORIGIN}"`

They all just return the exact string, without resolving to the variable.

Comment: Do you expcect `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` ?

Comment: No, I want whatever Origin value was sent, I figured out this hack, but I would like to know how to assign the value of one variable to another without relying on regex: `SetEnvIfNoCase ORIGIN ".+" ORIGINVAR=$0`